# What is the maximum length that $.parseJSON() can handle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a long json array that needs to be sent to an html5 mobile app and parsed. The whole array has around 700kb (gziped to 150kb) and it's 554976 characters long at the moment. But it  will increase on time.

Using jquery to parse the json, my app crashes while trying to parse it. And so does jsonlint, [json parser.fr](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and any other online json validator I try, so I'm guessing `eval()` is not an option either.

Might be a broad question but what is the maximum "acceptable" length for a json array?

I have already removed as much data as I can from the array, the only option I can think of is to split the array in 3-4 server calls and parse it separately in the app. Is there any other option?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @fabien for pointing that if jsonlint crashes there is a problem on the json. There was a hidden "space" character in one of the nodes. It was parsed correctly on the server but not on the client.

Comment: Do you really mean "crash" or more like "freeze" ?

Comment: A [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605586/is-there-a-limit-on-size-of-json-object-that-can-be-processed-by-browsers) query on stack overflow. The accepted answer also contains the analysis and approach followed by the developer to parse large JSON strings. Hope this points you towards a solution

Comment: `eval` would no doubt be faster and more memory efficient than `$.parseJSON`. Also have a look at `JSON.parse` (not fully cross browser)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912642/max-recommended-size-of-external-json-object-in-javascript has a 20mb JSON string being parsed. Are you sure your JSON object is properly formed?

Comment: @Petah From jQuery 2 source `parseJSON: JSON.parse,`. jQuery 1.x uses it for all browsers which support it.

Comment: The json is properly formed as I can parse it on the server side. It just freezes on the client side. I get no errors, it just stops on the  parsing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've parsed way bigger arrays with jquery.

My first guess is that there's an error in your json.

You have many ways to find it (sublime text could highlight the error but some time, it's a bit long). Try to paste it in a web tool like http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/. and use any of the buttons (to format or to send to the right view). It'll tell you where the error is.

Comment: That's a good tool, it actually parsed the json correctly! If i try directly on jsonlint it freezes. Which seems a little bit weird to me.

Comment: can you show us the json ? If lint freeze, there's a problem with it :)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. NDAs. Love them! But I found out the problem. There was a strange "empty space" character in one of the nodes. For some reason it was parsed correctly on c# but not on javascript. .net flagged it when i used a different parser! Great online tool btw! Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: This is because of the way jquery will parse it ; it won't escape the special characters, the spaces, the line breaks... If you are web based, you can proxy the datas by parsing it first with php / ruby (it will correct most of the errors) and then send it to your app.