# Is there a limit on size of json string that can be processed by browsers?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

[Is there a limit on size of json object that can be processed by browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605586/is-there-a-limit-on-size-of-json-object-that-can-be-processed-by-browsers#)

I am having the same question and adding to that.. When  I use mozilla firefox browser the page is crashing if my json string exceeds length 4097 characters and the same json works well with chrome. Please help

Comment: So just change to a POST request instead

Comment: I am getting JSON string from the database and when that string size exceeds 4097 characters the page crashes